# NoClassDefFoundError with VelocityEngineFactory when spring + velocity

Tags: maven, spring-mvc, velocity

```
spring 4.1.6.RELEASE maven
error:
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'accountController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: org.geekworld.service.AccountService org.geekworld.controller.AccountController.accountService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Error loading class [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.velocity.VelocityConfigurer] for bean with name 'velocityConfig' defined in class path resource [spring-servlet.xml]: problem with class file or dependent class; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/ui/velocity/VelocityEngineFactory
```

xml:

```
<bean id="velocityConfig" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.velocity.VelocityConfigurer">
        <property name="resourceLoaderPath" value="/WEB-INF"/>
        <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:velocity.properties"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.velocity.VelocityViewResolver">
        <property name="suffix" value=".vm"/>
        <property name="prefix" value="/"/>
        <property name="exposeSpringMacroHelpers" value="true"/>
        <property name="requestContextAttribute" value="content"/>
        <property name="exposeRequestAttributes" value="true"/>
        <property name="exposeSessionAttributes" value="true"/>
        <property name="contentType" value="text/html;charset=UTF-8"/>
        <property name="dateToolAttribute" value="dateTool"/>
        <!-- velocity toolbox -->
        <property name="toolboxConfigLocation" value="/WEB-INF/toolbox.xml"/>
    </bean>
```

Comment: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/ui/velocity/VelocityEngineFactory` are the jars added ??

Answer (score 1):

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/ui/velocity/VelocityEngineFactory
```

Indicates jar is not available for the context to load.

```
   <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.velocity/velocity -->
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
       <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
       <version>1.7</version>
   </dependency>

   <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.velocity/velocity-tools -->
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
       <artifactId>velocity-tools</artifactId>
       <version>2.0</version>
   </dependency>
```

Please make sure that you have these dependencies added.

Also required `vm` files should be in classpath to load and execute.